# Flowtype "Not covered by Flow" on object property chains

Tags: flowtype

I'm trying to use Flow, but I keep getting the "Not covered by Flow" warning, so my code is mostly underlined. I checked the Flow documentation, but it wasn't helpful regarding object property chaining, so **how do you get something like this to work?**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you are using a library that does not have type definitions.

With property lookups where the object is defined within the file, Flow has 100% code coverage without any types at all:

```
const foo = { bar: { baz: 2 } };
foo.bar.baz;
// 100% Flow coverage
```

Same goes for separate files:

**1.js**

```
// @flow
export default { bar: { baz: 2 } };
```

**2.js**

```
// @flow
import foo from './1.js'
foo.bar.baz;
// 100% code coverage
```

However, as soon as something is being imported from a file that Flow does not run on (either because it has flow turned off or because its a third-party library that does not use flow), Flow is not able to cover it.

**1.js**

```
// @noflow
export default { bar: { baz: 2 } };
```

**2.js**

```
// @flow
import foo from './1.js'
foo.bar.baz;
// 0% code coverage
```

In order to fix this, you need to give Flow information about the types.

You can do a couple of different things

- Make `a.js` covered by Flow.
- Add a [`a.js.flow` file that `declare`'s the types](https://flowtype.org/docs/declarations.html#declaration-files)
- If it's a third-party library [add a `flow-typed/a.js` file that adds declarations.](https://flowtype.org/docs/declarations.html)
- But be sure to check [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed) to see if a definition file already exists. (And contribute back!)

Hopefully this is helpful enough to give you at least a starting point

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Flow as well, but heres my take:

If you have two classes, A and B, and flow typechecking is not enabled on A, then B functions that call into it will be "uncovered".

```
// a.js
class A {
}

// b.js
/* @flow */
import A from './A'

class B {
  buildA():void {
    new A()        // I'm un-covered by Flow!
  }
}
```

Flow doesn't know anything about the structure of A, and so therefore can't provide any guarantees.